# Error Importing Work Item .csv File in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

When a user tried to import a work item or pbi .csv file format in Azure DevOps, he got an error (i.e invalid node id).

Comment: Add example of your csv file and error. Because your question does not describe enough information.

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander actually that's just the problem.  The only error text is "Invalid node id."

Answer (score 1):

The error means you used wrong Area ID or Iteration ID, etc. You need to check the ID values and use the correct ID in the csv file.

Comment: And it is specifically the "Area ID," not as much the "Area Path" at issue here.